# Visual Studio 2019 Class does not have a correct Copy Constructor C++

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli

I'm working on a project for uni and I was thinking about a simple game where you construct ships and battle with a fleet of 6 of them using visual studio code but when I try to constuct an object i always get an error of an incorrect copy constructor in "Ship" class. I humbly ask for help.(the change in this->is because i was trying everything to get it to work)

```
String^ tekst = MyForm2::textBox1->Text;
    int FP = int::Parse(MyForm2::textBox2->Text);
    int Armor = int::Parse(MyForm2::textBox3->Text);
    int Speed = int::Parse(MyForm2::textBox4->Text);
    int AA = int::Parse(MyForm2::textBox5->Text);
    int special= int::Parse(MyForm2::textBox6->Text);
    int hp = 15;

    if (radioButton1->Checked == true)
    {
        Ship s_1 = Ship (tekst, FP, hp, Armor, Speed, AA);

    }
```

```
ref class Ship
{
public:
    String^ nazwa;
    int FP;
    int HP;
    int ARMOR;
    int SPEED;
    int AA;
    Ship() {};
    Ship(String^ new_nazwa, int new_fp, int new_hp, int new_armor, int new_speed,int new_aa)
    {
        nazwa = new_nazwa;
        FP = new_fp;
        HP = new_hp;
        ARMOR = new_armor;
        SPEED = new_speed;
        AA = new_aa;
    };

};


ref class Destroyer : public Ship

{
public:
    Destroyer() {};
    Destroyer(String^ new_nazwa, int new_fp, int new_hp, int new_armor, int new_speed, int new_torp,int new_aa)
    {
        nazwa = new_nazwa;
        FP = new_fp;
        HP = new_hp;
        ARMOR = new_armor;
        SPEED = new_speed;
        TORP = new_torp;
        AA = new_aa;
    };
    int TORP;

};
ref class Battleship : public Ship

{
public:
    Battleship(String^ new_nazwa, int new_fp, int new_hp, int new_armor, int new_speed, int new_sec_fp,int new_aa)
    {
        this->nazwa = new_nazwa;
        this->FP = new_fp;
        this->HP = new_hp;
        this->ARMOR = new_armor;
        this->SPEED = new_speed;
        this->Sec_FP = new_sec_fp;
        this->AA = new_aa;
    };
    int Sec_FP;
};
ref class Carrier : public Ship

{
public:
    Carrier(String^ new_nazwa, int new_fp, int new_hp, int new_armor, int new_speed, int new_torp,int new_aa)
    {
        this->nazwa = new_nazwa;
        this->FP = new_fp;
        this->HP = new_hp;
        this->ARMOR = new_armor;
        this->SPEED = new_speed;
        this->TORP = new_torp;
        this->AA = new_aa;
    };
    int TORP;

};
ref class Cruiser : public Ship

{
public:
    Cruiser(String^ new_nazwa, int new_fp, int new_hp, int new_armor, int new_speed, int new_aa)
    {
        this->nazwa = new_nazwa;
        this->FP = new_fp;
        this->HP = new_hp;
        this->ARMOR = new_armor;
        this->SPEED = new_speed;
        this->AA = new_aa;
    };

};
```

Answer (score 0):

> `Ship s_1 = Ship (tekst, FP, hp, Armor, Speed, AA);`

This line attempts to create an instance of the reference type `Ship` on the stack with a syntax that invokes the copy constructor. This is allowed since VS2005, but with several caveats (quoted from [C++ Stack Semantics for Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/cpp-stack-semantics-for-reference-types?view=msvc-160)):

> *When you create an instance of a reference type using stack semantics, the compiler does internally create the instance on the garbage collected heap (using gcnew). [...] The compiler will not generate a copy constructor for a reference type*.

Following are possible ways to get it to work (without discussing the merits of creating ref types with stack semantics in general, which is covered at the the previous link).

- Do not use stack semantics. Instead:

  ```
  Ship ^s_1 = gcnew Ship(tekst, FP, hp, Armor, Speed, AA);
  ```
- Use stack semantics with direct construction, instead of copy-construction:

  ```
  Ship s_1(tekst, FP, hp, Armor, Speed, AA);
  ```
- Use the code as posted, but define a copy constructor for the `ref class Ship`:

  ```
  Ship(const Ship %other)
  {
    nazwa = other.nazwa;
    /* ... */
  }
  ```